# how to load all options in selector without select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

When I'm adding an options for a new product, there is a selector that must be used to select the options I need. But all the available options are required and must be visible without use of a selector.
How can I add to form each option by option_id, without using a selector?

HTML.file

```
<div class="ms-options">
    <p class="error" id="error_options"></p>

    <div class="options"></div>

    <div>
        <select name="options[0]" class="select_option">
            <option value="0" disabled="disabled" selected="selected"><?php echo $ms_options_add; ?></option>
            <?php foreach($options as $option) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option['option_id']?>"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS.file

```
// add
$('body').delegate(".select_option", "change", function() {
    $(this).children(':selected').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    var option_id = $(this).children(':selected').val();
    var select = this;

    $.get($('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=seller/account-product/jxRenderOptionValues&option_id=' + option_id, function(data) {
        var lastRow = $(select).parents('.ms-options').find('.option:last input:last').attr('name');

        if (typeof lastRow == "undefined") {
            var newRowNum = 1;
        } else {
            var newRowNum = parseInt(lastRow.match(/[0-9]+/g).shift()) + 1;
        }

        var data = $(data);
        data.find('input,select').attr('name', function(i,name) {
            if (name) return name.replace('product_option[0]','product_option[' + newRowNum + ']');
        });
        $('div.options').append(data);
    });
    $(this).val(0);
});
```

pls hlp

my attempt

html.file

```
<div class="ms-options">
    <p class="error" id="error_options"></p>



    <div>
            <?php foreach($options as $option) { ?>
            <div id="<?php echo $option['option_id']?>"></div>
            <?php echo addoption($option['option_id'])?>
            <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

js.file

```
$(function() {

    function addoption(optionid) {

        var option_id = optionid;
        $.get($('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=seller/account-product/jxRenderOptionValues&option_id=' + option_id, function(data) {


            $('div'."optionid").append(data);
        });
    });
});
```

but i've got this message

Fatal error: Call to undefined function addoption() in /home/moidomki/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/multiseller/account-product-form-options.tpl on line 9

looks like it's can't see my function?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You can't have `<option>` without `<select>`.

Comment: @Barmar, he/she wants to add an option to the select without referring to the select through its selector. This is probably a homework and the teacher probably wanted them to use $(this) instead of a selector inside the function passed to delegate. I carefully answered the question, to only specify how to not use the selector, but without taking all the fun from the op.

Comment: Lajos Arpad, thank you for an unswer!I Meant,that in the form of new product there is a selector, and all options needed to be selected to be available. But in truth, all these options are required and must be displayed in advance and in special order. So i want to get all that options and call them one by one. 
This is not the teacher gave me a job. I'm learning, and I have nobody to ask what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `delegate`. See your first parameter? It is `".select_option"`. This is where you specify the selector of the tag where you want to define the options. From here on you do not need to specify it again. Inside the function passed to `delegate` as a parameter, you can use `$(this)` instead. It is actually better to use `$(this)` inside `delegate` if possible, because then jquery will not have to search for it from the DOM.

See this example:

```
$( "table" ).delegate( "td", "click", function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
});
```

Taken from here.

EDIT:

Hereby I am giving some notes about the experiment taken by Yurii Litvinenko:

- let me start with nailing down that it is a very pleasant thing to see that people are actually trying to learn on their own. Off course, the experiment is flawed, but do not forget that the best way to learn it is to actually do it
- the actual problem you are being pointed to is that you are trying to call a javascript function using php. It is important to understand that your php code is called server-side, or backend and your javascript code is called client-side, or frontend. Your php is running on the server and your javascript is running on the user's computer, therefore, you cannot call a client-side function on server-side
- I do not see your select tag in your new experiment
- You are successfully filling your initial option set on the server if I am not mistaken
- If you intend to add options to your select already sent to your client-side, then you need to do it with javascript, like that:

  `function addOption(id, name) {
      $(".select_option").html(select_option.html() + '<option value="' + id + '">' + name + '</option>');
  }`

Comment: Lajos Arpad, I guess that I should not use the event and can cause all of these options on a straight line, without "delegate". but how?

Comment: @YuriiLitvinenko, I believe you should use it. The thing is that using $(this) inside the function given to delegate is better than searching in the whole DOM with $(".select_option"). I believe your teacher wants to show this to you as a possibility to write better code.

Comment: Lajos Arpad, i have no teacher, i'm studying by myself. anyway thank you i'll try to use your advice.

Comment: For your previous comment, you can create a variable, called myOptions, loop through the values and add them to it, like this: myOptions += '<option value="' + optionValue +'">' + optionText + '</option>. When you have all the options in your string, you can add them to your select: $(".select_option").html(myOptions). There are many possible solutions. I usually build up a string and add it to the select tag, or generate the elements on server-side.

Comment: Thank you, Lajos Arpad for your advice! First of all , I wish you good luck this year and all the others, and I wish you a merry Christmas . I tried your advice but I have not vіshlo as I wanted . moreover nothing at all happened. I wrote some code I would like you to look at whether it is the right direction ?